# How to create mock test cases for scalar valued function

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec-rails

I am calling a scalar valued function but having hard time trying to figure out how can i create mock test cases for it.

I just want to create some mock test cases like,

1. function returns successfully one value
2. function returns conversion error

I tried something below but here i have to call the actual function, which i dont want to because if database changes it'll cause the test case fail hence want to mock cases.

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe ScalarSqlFunction::Base do
  describe '#exec' do
    let!(:success) { 0 }

    context 'with valid input' do
      let(:response) {
        ScalarSqlFunction::CalcTotal(105)
      }
      before do
        allow(response)
          .to receive(return_code).and_return(success)
      end
      it 'returns success' do
        expect(response.return_code).to eq(success)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a mock object for ScalarSqlFunction::CalcTotal

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe ScalarSqlFunction::Base do
describe '#exec' do
  let!(:success) { 0 }

context 'with valid input' do
  let(:response) { double('Response') }
  before do
    allow(response)
      .to receive(return_code).and_return(success)
  end
  it 'returns success' do
    expect(response.return_code).to eq(success)
  end
end
end
end
```